# How to emit compiled scss and get output url with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm looking to do the following:

1. Import a `.scss` file into my JavaScript code
2. Have webpack compile the scss into css
3. Resolve any urls/imports
4. Export the css to a single file (and not bundle that css with any other scss imports!)
5. Within the JavaScript module, the `import` stores the file's output url.

Here's what I've tried:

To perform steps 1-3, I am using the following loaders (in order):

- `sass-loader`
- `resolve-url-loader`
- `postcss-loader`
- `css-loader`

To perform steps 4-5, it seemed like `file-loader` fit what I needed best, but the outputted file contents was JavaScript instead of CSS and looks like:

[image: file-loader file contents]

I've also tried using the loader that comes with `mini-css-extract-plugin`. The output file is properly compiled CSS, but I'm unable to import its url. Furthermore, I believe that it would bundle multiple scss imports (which I don't want).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I've found a solution just minutes after posting here.

Using [`extract-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/extract-loader/) will resolve the JS in the file after `css-loader` and convert it to plain CSS as desired in step 4. Then, using `file-loader` like I originally wanted will output the file and allow importing the output url as in step 5.

```
    {
        loader:'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].css'
        },
    },
    'extract-loader',
    ... // my other loaders mentioned above (css-loader, etc.)
```